# iPhone: UILocalNotification doesn't repeat the notification

Tags: iphone

I am trying to use UILocalNotification in my project. I want my application to get notified every 5 seconds (non stop) in the background. I am trying the following code. It is notifying my application only for the first time after 5 seconds, after installed. I want it to be notified continuously every 5 seconds without stop. How can i achieve it?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    // Initiating notification at app startup
    [self InitiateLocalNotification];

    return YES;
}

-(void) InitiateLocalNotification
{

    NSDate *notificationDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5];

    UILocalNotification *notify = [ [UILocalNotification alloc] init ];

    notify.fireDate = notificationDate;

    //notify.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

    notify.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

    notify.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

    //notify.alertBody = @"Local notification test";

    //notify.repeatInterval = 1;

    NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"notifiValue" forKey:@"notifiKey"];
    notify.userInfo = infoDict;

    // Schedule the notification
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notify];
    [notify release];

}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification 
{

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you need to register for the notification again if you receive any,

your code could be :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{ // Override point for customization after application launch.

self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

// Initiating notification at app startup
[self InitiateLocalNotification];

return YES;
}


-(void) InitiateLocalNotification
{

NSDate *notificationDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5];

UILocalNotification *notify = [ [UILocalNotification alloc] init ];

notify.fireDate = notificationDate;

//notify.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

notify.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

notify.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

//notify.alertBody = @"Local notification test";

//notify.repeatInterval = 1;

NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"notifiValue" forKey:@"notifiKey"]; notify.userInfo = infoDict;

// Schedule the notification
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notify];
[notify release];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification 
{
  // Need to register again
  [self InitiateLocalNotification];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried calling [self InitiateLocalNotification]; function again in didReceiveLocalNotification, but it is not notifying it from the second time interval onwards.

Answer (score 1):

You are only calling 
`[self InitiateLocalNotification];`

once, and therefore only scheduling one notification.

You must schedule each notification that you wish to receive (schedule notification 5 seconds from now, 10 seconds from now ... etc), since you don't have that kind of control over the repeat interval.

A solution would be to schedule the next one when you receive a notification, but that won't result in notifications scheduled exactly 5 seconds apart.

Comment: but if we are in background - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification 
 this method is not calling ,this is calling after we open the app